# Telephony TextBasedSmsColumns Date_Sent based time

Tags: android, sms

In the SMS database you can locate 2 times:

- date: the time (local based) when the SMS has been received or sent
- date_sent: the time when the SMS has sent by the sender (for sms received) or the time when the SMS has been processed by the sms-provider.

date_sent isn't based on local time (I think). Is based on UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outgoing SMS:

- DATE - local time of your device in moment when SMS was sent.
- DATE_SENT - not sure about it, but do not use it, may be 0.

Incoming SMS:

- DATE - local time of your device in moment when SMS was received.
- DATE_SENT - local time of remote device in moment when SMS was sent.

Comment: For incoming SMS date-sent is the local-time of remote device in moment when SMS was sent, but... in what locale? UTC? my locale? Thanks

Comment: The Matrix, UTC. Generally when you see time in number representation (as long type) in Andoird it means UTC in milliseconds.

Comment: Any idea why this number would be negative? Im trying to pull the date from an incoming SMS message and its coming back as a negative long...

Comment: @Agent404 - only one thing I can guess - the timestamp is a "big" number, bigger than int can contains. So maybe you try to get it as int, it will be negative because its bit representation.